# Is there a way to feed arguments to a dplyr function using a string variable? What is this called?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, if-statement, dplyr

In R is there a way to feed arguments (?) to a function like this:

```
df <- data.frame( ID = c(10, 20),
              strand = c(1,-1),
              type = c("pos", "neg") )

test1 <- "strand == \"-1\""
test2 <- "type == \"pos\""

df %>% dplyr::filter(test1)
df %>% dplyr::filter(test2)
```

My ultimate goal is a function that will filter the df using one column or the other, depending on the users preference:

```
strand_or_type <- function(df, strand_or_type) { 
    df <- data.frame( ID = c(10, 20),
              strand = (1,-1),
              type = ("pos", "neg") )

    if(strand_or_type == "strand"){
       col <- "strand == \"-1\""
    } else if(strand_or_type == "type") {
       col <- "type == \"pos\""
    }

    df %>% dplyr::filter(col)
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to describe this, will update ASAP if there is. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `parse_expr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    dplyr::filter(eval(rlang::parse_expr(test1)))
```

---

As a function

```
strand_or_type <- function(df, strand_or_type) { 
    str1 <- switch(strand_or_type,
          strand = "strand == \"-1\"",
          type = "type == \"pos\"")
    df %>%
      filter(eval(rlang::parse_expr(str1)))

}
```

-testing

```
 strand_or_type(df, "strand")
  ID strand type
1 20     -1  neg
> strand_or_type(df, "type")
  ID strand type
1 10      1  pos
```

---

Or instead of creating a string and evaluating, we may do

```
strand_or_type <- function(df, strand_or_type) { 
       to_filter <- switch(strand_or_type,
                     strand = -1,
      type = "pos")
      df %>%
         filter(if_any(all_of(strand_or_type), ~ .x == to_filter))
}
```

-testing

```
> strand_or_type(df, "strand")
  ID strand type
1 20     -1  neg
> strand_or_type(df, "type")
  ID strand type
1 10      1  pos
```

Comment: the first one makes sense, I was wondering if you could explain the second solution. Particularly the ```if_any(all_of(strand_or_type), ~ .x == to_filter)```

Comment: @SkyScraper It is a general solution where we wrap with `if_any` or `if_all` to return a single TRUE for each row if any of the columns looped in that rows satisfy the condition or all the columns respectively.  Here, we are passing a single column.  So, using that wouldn't create any issues (`if_any` vs `if_all`).  Or other option is to use `df %>% filter(pick(strand_or_type)[[1]] == to_filter)` or `df %>% filter(cur_data()[[strand_or_type]] == to_filter)` or `df %>% filter(.data[[strand_or_type]] == to_filter)`

Answer (score 1):

With `filter_` you can pass a string.

```
strand_or_type <- function(df, strand_or_type) { 

  if(strand_or_type == "strand"){
    col <- "strand == \"-1\""
  } else if(strand_or_type == "type") {
    col <- "type == \"pos\""
  }
  
  dplyr::filter_(df,col)
}
```

Comment: filter with the underscore - `filter_()`, is a depreciated function it should be replaced with more up-to-date functions.